# MongoDB for Windows 32 bit with SSL

Tags: windows, mongodb, ssl, windows-7, 32-bit

I understand I need to download an old version of MongoDB so it will work on a Windows 32-bit operating system. But it appears all the old versions come without SSL. Can I still have SSL or will I need to upgrade my operating system?

Comment: The older versions of MongoDB (for example v3.6) have the [Security](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/security/) features.

Comment: Do you really have a 32-bit Windows running in 2021?